# Understanding Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

```
Enter your regex: a?
Enter input string to search: ababaaaab
I found the text "a" starting at index 0 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "a" starting at index 2 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "" starting at index 3 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "a" starting at index 4 and ending at index 5.
I found the text "a" starting at index 5 and ending at index 6.
I found the text "a" starting at index 6 and ending at index 7.
I found the text "a" starting at index 7 and ending at index 8.
I found the text "" starting at index 8 and ending at index 8.
I found the text "" starting at index 9 and ending at index 9.

Enter your regex: a*
Enter input string to search: ababaaaab
I found the text "a" starting at index 0 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "a" starting at index 2 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "" starting at index 3 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "aaaa" starting at index 4 and ending at index 8.
I found the text "" starting at index 8 and ending at index 8.
I found the text "" starting at index 9 and ending at index 9.

Enter your regex: a+
Enter input string to search: ababaaaab
I found the text "a" starting at index 0 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "a" starting at index 2 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "aaaa" starting at index 4 and ending at index 8.
```

---

The above example is from `Java Documentation` on quantifiers.
From what I understand from the examples given above, Here are how the greedy quantifiers work:

### ? and *

Will look for presence of absence of the mentioned character. If the character preceding them is not found, it marks that location as a zero-length match.
`*` goes for a character by character match while `?` goes for a group.

### +

`+` will go for group by group matching of the regex. It does not make zero-length matches.

My question is:
Is my understanding of the quantifiers correct or am I messing something ?
Also, is there any brain-friendly guide to java regex (there is none available on Google that targets beginners) ?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is the de-facto guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - goes for a character by character match while ? goes for a group.

`*` matches zero or more.  `?` matches zero or 1.

Neither of these have anything to do with groups or characters.  A "group" or "capturing group" in regex parlance is a parenthesized element that can be extracted separately by the `java.util.regex.Matcher.group` method.

`(foo)*` matches `""`, `"foo"`, and `"foofoo"` so obviously the body does not need to be a single character.

`(foo)?` matches `""` and `"foo"` but not `"foofoo"`.

> - will go for group by group matching of the regex. It does not make zero-length matches.

No.  `+` matches the body one or more times so `x*` is equivalent to `(?:x+)?`.  The `+` operator can perform zero-length matches just fine.  `()+` matches the empty string.

Comment: why (foo)? matches "foofoo" ?
it has to be zero or once right ? why it is matching foo times ?

Comment: @Hiro_Hamada `(foo)?` can be found all strings because the empty string is a substring of every input.  There's nothing in there, like a `^` (start of input) or `$` (end of input-ish) to prevent the zero-length match from being valid.  To match only "" and "foo" you'd use `^(foo)?\z` in Java.

Comment: @Hiro_Hamada The Java API is a tad confusing.  `Pattern.matches("(foo)?", "foofoo") == false` but `Pattern.compile("(foo)?").matcher("foofoo").find()` is true because `matches` assumes it applies to the whole input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your understanding is correct.

For a guide, just look for regex; there's nothing too specific to Java except for function calls and what not. For example, 1-second search lead to http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html

**Edit**: Explosion Pills points to http://www.regular-expressions.info/ which is an excellent source. It has a [Java-specific section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) but of course the patterns themselves are still in standard regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `?` matches if the character appears 0 or 1 time, `*` matches if it appears any number of times (including 0), and `+` matches if it appears at least one time.